# Error when I compile kernel 3.3.2 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: kernel, 12.04

I thinks is not a bug of ubuntu. This is the output:

```
  OBJCOPY arch/x86/boot/vmlinux.bin
  HOSTCC  arch/x86/boot/tools/build
  BUILD   arch/x86/boot/bzImage
Setup is 16800 bytes (padded to 16896 bytes).
System is 4599 kB
CRC f77d64c0
Kernel: arch/x86/boot/bzImage is ready  (#1)
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 3268 modules
ERROR: "__modver_version_show" [drivers/staging/rts5139/rts5139.ko] undefined!
WARNING: modpost: Found 4 section mismatch(es).
To see full details build your kernel with:
'make CONFIG_DEBUG_SECTION_MISMATCH=y'
make[1]: *** [__modpost] Error 1
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Comment: where did you get the source to build the kernel

Comment: Have the same problem with latest stable 3.3.2 from kernel.org Have not solved this problem yet. Related: http://superuser.com/questions/360089/modver-version-show-undefined-error-when-building-linux-kernel-3-0-4-version http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29955/modver-version-show-undefined-error-during-make

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu 12.04 and kernel 3.3.4 I've disabled module:

```
sed -i s/CONFIG_RTS5139=m/CONFIG_RTS5139=n/ .config
```